# zebra scanner integration in android

Tags: android, xamarin.android, barcode-scanner, android-bluetooth

we are using symbol ls4278  bluetooth scanner to integrate in android application. It is connected as keyboard and types scanned barcode in any edittext field... 
After scanner OnKeyUp event is called.

```
 public override bool OnKeyUp(Keycode keyCode, KeyEvent e)
        {
        ..
    }
```

I was searching documentation and android sdk, but I can't found such one. But for LI4278 they have android sdk here : https://www.zebra.com/us/en/support-downloads/scanners/general-purpose-scanners/li4278.html 
here is also documentation for sdk but LS4278 is not in supported device list.

Does anyone implemented LS4278 scanner in android devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The LS4278 product page is here: https://www.zebra.com/us/en/support-downloads/scanners/general-purpose-scanners/ls4278.html and lists support for the "Windows Scanner SDK" ONLY.  The LS4278 was discontinued on September 24th 2012 so I am not surprised it does not have Android support.  As you say, its successor, the LI4278 does have Android support.  As the other answer states, if you want more control over how you receive data then I suggest trying SPP if the scanner supports it.

Answer (score 1):

If it works as a bluetooth keyboard, then no support is needed.  Just capture the key events, and react to the data when enter is pressed.  Its just a mediocre experience and can mess with on screen keyboards and stop them from using an actual bluetooth keyboard.  If the scanner supports SPP, you can pretty trivially parse the scan data out of it via bluetooth serial (I did this about 2 weeks ago).

Comment: user don't want to press enter, scanner itself doesn't press any other buttons expect bar code numbers... about SPP I don't know, here is no documentation about this (or I couldn't find).. So , I need to test somehow

Comment: The scanner itself sends the enter key as the last character of a barcode.  So you can capture that.  This is one of the rare instances where onKeyUp will actually work for that.  As for SPP-  I'll post a 2nd answer for that, I actually did it myself a few weeks ago.

Answer (score 1):

```
    BluetoothAdapter bta = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    if(bta != null) {
        Set<BluetoothDevice> devices = bta.getBondedDevices();
        for (final BluetoothDevice device : devices) {
            BluetoothClass btClass = device.getBluetoothClass();
            if (btClass.getMajorDeviceClass() == 0x1f00) {
                //Only look at devices which are considered uncategorized, so we don't screw up any bt headset, leyboard, mouse, etc
                new DeviceThread(device).start();
            }
        }
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_BOND_STATE_CHANGED);
        registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                int state = intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_BOND_STATE, BluetoothDevice.BOND_NONE);
                if (state == BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED) {
                    new DeviceThread(device).start();
                } else if (state == BluetoothDevice.BOND_NONE) {
                    DeviceThread thread = threadMap.get(device.getAddress());
                    if (thread != null) {
                        thread.interrupt();
                    }
                }
            }
        }, filter);
    }


private class DeviceThread extends Thread {
    private BluetoothDevice device;

    public DeviceThread(BluetoothDevice device) {
        this.device = device;
        threadMap.put(device.getAddress(), this);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            BluetoothSocket socket = device.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB"));
            socket.connect();
            InputStream inputStream = socket.getInputStream();

            while (!Thread.interrupted() && socket.isConnected()) {
                inputStream.skip(5);
                String data = "";
                do {
                    int code = inputStream.read();
                    char character = (char) code;
                    data = data + character;
                } while (inputStream.available() > 0);
                data = data.substring(0, data.length() - 2);

                if (scannerEventListener != null) {

                    scannerEventListener.onScan(data);
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.d("GABE", "Exiting thread");
    }
}
```

This code will register for bluetooth devices being paired, then check and see if they're unknown device types (scanners don't have a device class).  If so, it will start a thread to listen for that device.  When its unbonded, it will interrupt that thread.  On the thread it opens up a SPP connection to the device and waits for input.  When it gets it, it parses the input and sends the result to a listener.

For this to work, the scanner needs to be in SPP mode.  Some scanners support it, some don't, and how to set it into that mode varies (the one on my desk has a control barcode I need to scan to set the mode).  Generally I would code for it to accept either type of input-  hardware keyboard mode or SPP.